# Following xv6/Linux forking and waitpid processes

Tags: fork, system-calls, waitpid, xv6

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int pid;
    if ( !(pid=fork()))
    {
        while (((count<2) && (pid=fork()) ) {
            count++;
            printf("%d",count)
       }
       if(count>0)
       {
           printf("%d", count);
       }
    }
    if (pid) {
        waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
        count = count<<1;
        printf("%d", count)
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble reading this piece of code. I can't figure out how many system calls are made or even remotely trace them. This is leading me to not be able to understand how the output works. I am assuming the scheduler can do anything. What are all possible outputs and how many system calls are made?

Comment: I included an image of the code, unless you can't see the imgur link. I will add the code in also.

Comment: To count system calls in xv6 you have two options, count them manually, or write a program to do so. For manual counting, a list of available system calls can be found in [user.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/34f060c3dcf3bf3dde683df9ff9872bc9f1d5d14/user.h#L4). In the code above, `fork` and `wait` are explicit system calls. If you look at the code for `printf`, you will see that it too makes a system call `write`.

Answer (score 0):

Launch with `strace -f ./myprogram` to trace all system calls.

From looking at the code, about 3 additional processes will be created.

Comment: Just a note, `strace` is not availble in xv6. OP listed Linux in their question, but  not really correct to do so. xv6 is an ultra simple Unix variant.